# como obtener un certificado instalado en pc cliente con javascript y enviarlo al servidor para usarlo con php?

Tags: php, javascript

Necesito obtener un certificado instalado en el pc cliente con el navegador(javascript) y enviarlo al servidor para firmar un documento pdf generado con alguna librería como TCPDF(php). Alguien que conozca sobre esto para que me pueda orientar por favor. El certificado lo quieren comprar en una empresa chilena llamada https://firma.cl/ o www.e-sign.cl . Es un certificado de Firma Electrónica Avanzada (FEA). Nunca he hecho esto así que si me pueden ayudar a evitar mayores complicaciones con esto se los agradecería.

Comment: ¿pudiste encontrar algo sobre este tema?, estoy igual que tu, y no encuentro nada que me ayude
Un saludo

Comment: la verdad es que no amigo